# How can I get the flat column names of a dataframe from Avro data?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have many Avro files that have a quite deep nested structure for different data types. What I need is creating a dataframe from these files that have columns names as dot-field separate names until the"primitive types" (string, int, map, arrays etc) . For example:

```
root
 |--  family: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- person: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- familyName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- givenName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fullName: string (nullable = true)
etc
```

will be turned to a dataframe with column names:

```
family.person.type, family.person.title, family.person.title, family.person.familyName, family.person.givenName, family.person.fullName, etc
```

I know that you can use something like `df.select(col("*"))` but that does not go in depth and stops at the first level. I have tried different things included this:

```
    def flat_struct_schema(schema, prefix=None):
        if not isinstance(schema, StructType):
            col_name = f'{prefix}.{schema.name}' if prefix else schema.name
            if 'struct' in schema.simpleString():
                flat_struct_schema(schema, col_name)
            else:
                return [col_name]
        else:
            for fld in schema.fields:
                flat_struct_schema(fld, prefix)
```

but it does not work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function should help by exploding the array columns first, then flattening the struct columns :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, explode
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, ArrayType
def flatten_df(df):
    while True:
        # Process ArrayType columns
        array_cols = [field.name for field in df.schema.fields if isinstance(field.dataType, ArrayType)]
        if array_cols:
            df = df.withColumn(array_cols[0], explode(col(array_cols[0])))
            continue

        # Process StructType columns
        struct_cols = [field.name for field in df.schema.fields if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType)]
        if struct_cols:
            for field in struct_cols:
                for subfield in df.schema[field].dataType.fields:
                    df = df.withColumn(f"{field}-{subfield.name}", col(f"{field}.{subfield.name}"))
                df = df.drop(field)
            continue

        break
    return df
```

This should take care of the deeply nested columns and provide a flattened structure. Btw in the code above I have chosen to have a hyphen as the separator. I would propose this or the underscore character instead of the dot separator.

If you'd like to visualize the structure of the flattened DataFrame, you can simply call the printSchema() method on the output of the function above.

If you're interested in generating the flattened schema without actually performing the operations to flatten the DataFrame itself, you can achieve this by recursively traversing the DataFrame's schema and constructing the new column names.

```
def generate_flat_schema(schema, prefix=""):
    fields = []
    for field in schema.fields:
        if isinstance(field.dataType, StructType):
            fields += generate_flat_schema(field.dataType, prefix=prefix + field.name + "-")
        elif isinstance(field.dataType, ArrayType) and isinstance(field.dataType.elementType, StructType):
            fields += generate_flat_schema(field.dataType.elementType, prefix=prefix + field.name + "-")
        else:
            fields.append(prefix + field.name)
    return fields

# Generate a list of flattened column names
flat_schema = generate_flat_schema(df.schema)

# Print the flattened column names
for column in flat_schema:
    print(column)
```